# GD LIB how to convert every uploaded images successfully into jpg type?

Tags: php, function, image-resizing, gdlib

please help me out with my current function to make it convert any other image types successfully into a proper jpg image type.

here is my function

```
    function resize_image($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){
    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width = 250; $height = 250;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagealphablending($img_src, false);
    imagesavelalpha($img_src, true);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 90);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}
```

Thanking you for your time and help in advance

Comment: Is something not working?

Comment: @kerbholz yes i face an issue, though i have restricted other image types allowing only jpg but at times some uploaded images by users are completely black. i guess they somehoe manage to upload png or gif?

Comment: maybe if could convert any uploaded image into jog then this issue will get solved?

Comment: If it is not jpg you will fail. Use [imagecreatefromstring()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) instead. This can guess the real format.

Comment: "_convert any other image types_" And you also want to allow other types (TIFF, Bmp, WebP, PNG, HEIF ...) to be uploaded?

Comment: @MarkusZeller please help me out with my above function for make it work in your way? its been a weeb i am trying but unable to get help any solution from anywhere. il be really greatful.

Comment: out of 100 one or two images are completely black. il really appreciate you guys help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not jpg you will fail. Use [imagecreatefromstring()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) instead. This can guess the real format.

Replace the code like this

```
$img_src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($oldimage_name));
```

Comment: so if i replace the line $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name); with your code will help sort my issue?

Comment: Yes, I guess so.

Comment: i just tried but after submitting the form the page turns blank

Comment: image got uploaded without resizing it

Comment: Make sure you did not create a syntax error by missing brackets or something, if your page "turns white".

Comment: ok i see these are conflicting imagealphablending($img_src, false);
    imagesavelalpha($img_src, true);, should i remove it?

Comment: Sure, whilest jpg does not support an alpha channel.

Comment: Thanks mate works now. hoping i do not see anymore black images :) GBU